# Python to send a command line to Zebra Designer For Developers

Tags: python, zebra-printers

Is there a way that Python can send or in other words, exist a command line that can be send via Python to the " Zebra Designer For Developers Software" to generate the PRN File?

I guess I should add a little bit more context about my question.

I'm working on a software to print labels using NiceLabel Software, the label I need to print is a dynamic label, this means that label information and layout is constantly changing.

I'm able to print the label however if for some reason I need to update the Label Layout a new PRN file needs to be generated, so far I has being do it manually but this is kind of odd since the main reason of my using python is to eliminate the human error

What I'm trying to do is to use Python to generate the PRN file instead users generating the file manually

Please see below a code that we are working on

```
 ## Imports
 from configparser import ConfigParser
 from zebra import Zebra

 ## Testing Variables
 NUM = "128077-00S"
 SER_NUM = "3132J908A6"
 MODEL = "EM000"

 ## Get Config File
 config = ConfigParser()
 config.read('config.ini')

 ## Set Config Variables
 printer = config['printer_setup'].get('printer')
 prnFile = config['label_setup'].get('label')

 ## Read Label File
 labelFile = open(prnFile)
 label = labelFile.read()
 labelFile.close()

 ## Printing
 z = Zebra()
 try:
     z.getqueues().index(printer)
 except ValueError:
     print("Printer Not Found: " + printer)
     input("\nPress enter to continue...")
 else:
     z.setqueue(printer)
     out = label
     out = out.replace("NUM", NUM)
     out = out.replace("SER_NUM", SER_NUM)
     out = out.replace("MODEL", MODEL)
     z.output(out)
     print("Label Printed Successfully!")
     input("\nPress enter to continue...")
```

thanks for your help !

Comment: Have you tried making a template PRN file, then load different config files to store into that?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you could replace your first three, or four, "test variables" + config file with [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) usage.

Then you run the script with any arguments you want, such as

```
python3 app.py -c config.ini --num="128077-00S" --sernum="3132J908A6" --model="EM000"
```

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer That is correct, the variables "num, sernum and model" I'm able to manipulate with no issues. however, based on the model the label layout and regulatory information should change, so, when I update the icons on the label, I need to generate a new PRN file. That's what I need to figure it out... how to do it using python instead the actual Zebra Design Software

Comment: Well, I see `prnFile = config['label_setup'].get('label')`, which you then read, so use a different config file?

Comment: Hi OneCricketeer, please see below my ini file 

     {[printer_setup]}
     {printer = ZDesigner ZD420-203dpi ZPL}

     {[label_setup]}
     {label = EM000_Unit.prn}

Comment: That's fine. I'm saying make a new file, and use a different `label` value, with a different `prn` file

Comment: (btw, I know nothing about Zebra printers / library, but seems you just need to refactor your code to be more parameterized, thus what my answer is addressing)

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer that's actually my last option, since we need to handle more than 100 different labels, I would have to create and maintain 100+ different PRN files. But, If I can figure it how to create the PRN file via command line, I just need to point to the correct file, generate the PRN and print

Comment: I don't know what format `.prn` files have, but Python can write any binary file on disk, yes... `f = open('newfile.prn', 'w')` and use `f.write()`

Comment: https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Creating-a-PRN-File-using-ZebraDesigner?language=en_US

Comment: Looks like a binary file with a bunch of control characters, that I personally don't understand, but like I said nothing prevents Python from writing that